# How to import Sigleton java class in karate feature file

Tags: java, karate

Trying the import Singleton class in Karate feature file, getting the below issue.

```
js failed:
>>>>
01: Java.type('db/utils/DefaultDBHelper')
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host class 
db/utils/DefaultDBHelper is not allowed or does not exist.
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be dots and the class should be present on the classpath.

```
Java.type('db.utils.DefaultDBHelper')
```